# Meaning of "trade" and "back-charged"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

There is this stair-case in a building, possible for emergency. On the door out (which can be open only from inside) I read

> Emergency exit only. **Trades observed using this exit will be back-charged lock-up time**. Use West Doors Only.

What does it mean?

Comment: Where is it (at least the country)?

Comment: It's not comprehensible to me.

Comment: @snailboat Sorry I corrected it.

Comment: This is obviously just a guess, but I believe that *trades* is jargon for tradesman (so possibly employees or contractors who do business here) and I would surmise that this door probably has a pushbar on it to allow exit in case of emergencies but when it is used, some manual process must be followed to securely lock it again.  The sign is a warning to the tradesmen to use the West Doors only otherwise if they are caught using *this* door they will be charged (required to pay, maybe out of their paycheck or added to their invoice) for the time it takes the management to re-secure the door.

Comment: @jim, more likely deducted from their invoice. Tradesmen are probably billing the building operator for their services, and when they are "back-charged" the building is charging them instead.

Comment: Could be.  Dunno.

Comment: @Jim I think it makes sense. I was thinking *trades* means *traffic*. I didn't think about employees. You can post your comment as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @Jim

> trades is jargon for tradesman (so possibly employees or contractors who do business here)

and *back-charged* means that

> if they are caught using this door they will be charged (required to pay, maybe out of their paycheck or added to their invoice) for the time it takes the management to re-secure the door.

Comment: @Theta30-  +1 Nice.